# Conversion from char to int does something weird

Tags: c++, embedded

Im working with a Particle Photon to make a digital watch + alarm clock. I am using a TFT screen, and i have drawn some digits on it which i can increment and change "digit index" with some buttons that i connected to my Photon - with the purpose of setting the time of a scheduled alarm. The function under is the one i call when a button is clicked, and its parameter is what "digit index" the "cursor" on my screen is at, which i can navigate with my buttons. This works fine however, all the way until 9 - where my screen starts displaying ASCII smileys and other letters instead of digits. I tried putting an if statement, that when the variable temp is higher than 9, it is set to 0 - which is what i ultimately want to achieve. This did not work, and it keeps displaying ASCII letters when it exceeds 9. Then i decided to try to print temp to console at button click, but then the first letter it prints is 49 and not 0? What??

I am not too seasoned with C/C++, but i do have a hunch that before im incrementing temp, i am doing the conversion from the char array timeSet wrong. What do you guys think?

```
void replaceDigitFromIndex(int selectorIndex) {
    tft.setTextSize(4);
    tft.setTextColor(ST7735_RED);
    tft.setCursor(4, 20);
    tft.print(timeSet);

    int temp = 0;

    if(selectorIndex == 1) {
        temp = (int) timeSet[0];
        temp++;
        timeSet[0] = (char) temp;
    }

    if(selectorIndex == 2) {
        temp = (int) timeSet[1];
        temp++;
        timeSet[1] = (char) temp;
    }

   if(selectorIndex == 3) {
        temp = (int) timeSet[3];
        temp++;
        timeSet[3] = (char) temp;
   }

   if(selectorIndex == 4) {
        temp = (int) timeSet[4];
        temp++;
        timeSet[4] = (char) temp;
    }

}
```

Comment: There is no language C/C++, they are two separate ones (and you seem to be using C++ since you have member functions)

Comment: The characters representing 0 through 9 to not themselves have the values they represent. In [ASCII](https://www.asciitable.com/) the `'0'` character have the numeric value 48.

Comment: A part from the ASCII issue here, as pointed out by others, I would recommend you to read about types conversions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The characters `'0'`-`'9'` are [ASCII Characters](https://www.asciitable.com/) 48-57*.

If you want to add one and have them loop, you can do:

```
//conversion to int is implicit, no need for (int)
int temp = timeSet[i] - '0'; //Subtract char '0' to map to ints [0,9]
temp = (temp + 1) % 10; //loop around 10
timeSet[i] = temp + '0'; //Add back char '0' to map back to chars ['0', '9']
```

---

<sup>*For you at least (since you've told us that `'1'` outputs 48 so you must be using ASCII or some superset of ASCII like UTF-8), but there's no guarantee every compiler will behave like this. This and readability are the reasons I do `- '0'` in my code. The digit characters are always contiguous. Thanks @Pete!</sup>

Comment: Formally, the characters '0' - '9' are simply characters, in whatever encoding the compiler uses. That's usually ASCII, but it can be something else. However, for all character encodings, the conversion `timeSet[i] - '0'` will convert the character value to the corresponding digit value. That is, the **code** in this answer is correct, although the explanation and comments assumes things that aren't required.

Comment: Re: "cast to int is implicit" -- no, never. A cast is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion. A cast is always explicit. The **conversion** to `int` here is implicit.

Comment: @PeteBecker fair enough. I've never encountered a compiler that didn't use ASCII (or some superset). Also good catch on my verbiage with the conversion, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In ASCII, there is only a representation of single characters and particularly for numbers only digits from 0 (char 48) to 9 (char 57).
When you go over 9, you'll get the char '9'+1 which is ':'.
You are right about putting an if statement for when the int is over 9.
But make sure the if is on the int not the character.